# Infinite scroll + back button like jabong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a functionality wherein on clicking the back button, i come back to the same position. A good example may be http://www.jabong.com/men/clothing/mens-t-shirts/ . Here, if you scroll down and hit on a product, and click back from the product page, you reach the same position of the page where that product is.

The example shown here doesn't append anything in the url to remember the position. Also, it doesn't use pushstate or history.js (not loading through ajax).

Any insights into how I can do this?

Comment: is there any plugin or code to achive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they use something like:

```
anchor = $('#foo');
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: anchor.offset().top},'fast');
```

cos i find after saved.

```
class="lastproduct added"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click in a product, it trigger a function that insert a cookie with current page and SKU clicked.
So, when you return, a function get this cookie, load all pages and set scroll position and delete de cookie with the following function:

```
scrollToLastViewedProduct: function() {
    var a = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($("#" + lastViewedCatalogDetail.sku).length) {
        $(window).scrollTop(a + 1);
        $(window).scrollTop($("#" + lastViewedCatalogDetail.sku).offset().top)
    }
    lastViewedCatalogDetail.removeCatalogCookie()
}
```